# Can anybody provide a MISRA C++ compliant 'offsetof' macro/template/function that works with static_assert?

Tags: c++, c++11, misra

I'm trying to write defensive code and put `static_assert<>` to ensure a structure's member has a specific offset to satisfy some hardware requirements

MISRA C++ Rule 18-2-1 says "The macro offsetof shall not be used", so we've 'undef'd offsetof.

We've provided some template things, but they all fail when used in `static_assert<>`

I've been unable to find something that works with C++11 `static_assert<>` across compilers.

```
struct Commands
{
    uint32_t command[4];
};

struct DMA_Bundle
{
    struct header_
    {
        uint32_t num_of_elems;
        uint8_t reserved[60];
    } header;
    Commands array[16];
};
```

I'm trying to assure that `array` is 64 bytes from the beginning.

```
static_assert(offsetof(DMA_Bundle,array)==64,"zoinks");
```

Does works, but MISRA says but I can't use that. (and I can't argue with our functional safety people :/)

I've tried the following, and generally they don't work:

```
static_assert(offsetofarray()==64,"bar");
static_assert(myoffsetof(DMA_Bundle::array)==64,"double_zoinks");
```

The explicit `offsetofarray()` constexpr function does work under GCC 7.5.0, but it fails under later GCC and Clang (which is what our embedded processor tools use).  It fails with 'non constant condition for static_assert'.

The other seems to complain of "invalid use of non-static data member 'DMA_Bundle::array'"

And, for what it's worth, I'm limited to C++11.

Comment: So why not just assert that the size of the header is 64 bytes? You already have that part neatly compartmentalized.

Comment: @Taekahn  just trying to be defensive and ensure nothing else changes in the future or somebody adds another variable.

Comment: You could always write a test that fails if the array isn’t where you expect. Write 64 bytes of data to the object then access the array through normal means and see if you have the correct data at the start of the array

Comment: You could try the [hacky implementations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof). Although they have undefined behavior, maybe they do work in your case.

Comment: "and I can't argue with our functional safety people" They can't be the ones making the calls for when to do deviations. It should rather be a decision made by one or several of the most seasoned C programmers in the company. Otherwise you are _creating_ hazards instead of avoiding them.

Comment: Anyway, a work-around might be `static_assert(sizeof (DMA_Bundle::header_) == 64, "yikes");` This takes possible trailing padding of the struct in account so it ought to be the very same thing as the `offsetof` macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Some background:**

> And, for what it's worth, I'm limited to C++11

And here is your first problem...

MISRA C++:2008 only allows the use of C++:2003 - anything after this is out of scope.

> MISRA C++ Rule 18-2-1 says "The macro offsetof shall not be used", so we've 'undef'd offsetof.

Use of `#undef` is a violation of *required* Rule 16-0-3 (and it is unnecessary to `#undef offsetof`)

---

**Now to address the main point:**

Rule 18-2-1 is a *required* Rule which seeks to protect against *undefined behaviour* when the types of the operands are incompatible.

> Does works, but MISRA says but I can't use that. (and I can't argue
> with our functional safety people :/)

The problem with many clip-board monitors is they can tick boxes, but adopt a  "MISRA says no" attitude without understanding what MISRA actually says...

My suggestion, especially if only being used when associated with `static_assert()` is to raise a deviation (see section 4.3.2 and the extended guidance in MISRA Compliance).

A deviation is a perfectly legitimate approach, where a Rule may be causing an inconvenience, but the *undefined behaviour* is not applicable.

---

ETA (noting discussion with Lundin about C): In MISRA C:2004, there was an equivalent guideline (Rule 20.6) which likewise imposed a blanket restriction on `offsetof` - in MISRA C:2012 this blanket restriction was dropped, with the *undefined behaviour* captured by the general Rule 1.3

In many respects, this makes justification of a MISRA C++ deviation easier - as the rationale would be matching the MISRA C decision.

**See profile for affiliation**

Comment: exactly, instead of the cure that kills the patient.

Comment: This rule was dropped in MISRA C:2012 so maybe make a permanent deviation. From what I can tell from the rationale, the main reason is that `offsetof` is unreliable when using bit-fields (C17 7.19/3). The correct and sound solution to that problem is to ban the root cause, namely the use of bit-fields in safety-related software.

Comment: @Lundin - I've deleted that comment, and updated my answer more fully.